# How do I clear satis "cache" so I can rebuild from scratch?

Tags: php, mercurial, composer-php, satis

I'm using satis to curate several hosted Mercurial repos. One of the repos had a bookmark 'stable' which satis scanned and created an entry for in packages.json. I stripped the branch, removed the remote repo and repushed. Now when I run `satis build ...` it still makes an entry for stable which is pointing to a changeset that no longer exists. How can I make satis re-scan or build from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just have to clear the composer cache in ~/.composer/cache and it will rescan bookmarks and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to see if there are tar files in the web/dist folder of your installation? If so you can just remove these and Satis will download the more up-to-date code the next time you build.